# Total variation distance between 2 probabilities

Tags: markov-chains, monte-carlo

I am reading [Diaconis, P. (2009). The markov chain monte carlo revolution](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2009-46-02/S0273-0979-08-01238-X/S0273-0979-08-01238-X.pdf).

Section **2.3 Convergence** defines the total variation distance between 2 probabilities (fixed $x$):

$$\lVert K^n_x-\pi \rVert_{TV}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_y \lvert K^n(x,y)-\pi(y)\rvert = \max_{A\subseteq \mathcal{X}} \;\lvert K^n(x,A)-\pi(A)\rvert$$

I can't fit the last equality in my head. Why should it be true (for countable sets)? I've done some numerical tests and it seems indeed right :)

How to prove it?

---

Related to:

- https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/410079/total-variation-norm

Comment: In your case, let $A$ be exactly those $y$ for which $K^n(x,y)-\pi(y)>0$.  That's one of the ways of achieving the max in your displayed formula.

Comment: Thanks! This comment makes it obvious. Since both probabilities must sum up to 1, it must be that $K^n(x,A)-\pi(A)=\pi(A^c)-K^n(x,A^c)$.